# How to change the colour of a single line in a graph

Tags: plotting

Basically i want to change the colour of a single line or 'band' in a ListLinePlot. The first image is the graph i have and the second is the format i'm trying to put the minimum and maximum negative lines in. Thanks in advance

[image: Graph 1]

[image: Graph 2]

Edit -  My code:

```
zigzaghamiltonian[n_, k_, t2_, phi_, delta_] := Table[
   If[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && v == (u + 1), -2*Cos[k/2],
        If[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && v == (u - 1), -2*Cos[k/2],
        If[Mod[u + v - 1, 4] == 0 && Abs[u - v] < 2, -1,
      If[
       Mod[u, 2] != 0 && (v == (u + 2) || v == (u - 2)), -t2*2*
        Cos[phi + k/2],
       If[
        Mod[u, 2] == 0 && (v == (u + 2) || v == (u - 2)), -t2*2*
         Cos[k/2 - phi], 
        If[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && u == v, -t2*2*Cos[phi + k] + delta, 
         If[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && u == v, -t2*2*Cos[k - phi] - delta, 
          0]]]]]]],
   {u, 2*n}, {v, 2*n}];
vx[n_, k_, t2_, phi_] := Table[
   If[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && v == (u + 1), -Sin[k/2],
        If[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && v == (u - 1), Sin[k/2],
     If[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && v == (u + 2), -t2*Sin[k/2]*Exp[-I*phi],
      If[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && v == (u + 2), -t2*Sin[k/2]*Exp[I*phi], 
       If[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && v == (u - 2), -t2*Sin[k/2]*Exp[I*phi],
        If[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && v == (u - 2), -t2*Sin[k/2]*Exp[-I*phi], 
         If[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && u == v, -t2*2*Sin[phi + k], 
          If[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && u == v, -t2*2*Sin[k - phi], 0]]]]]]]],
   {u, 2*n}, {v, 2*n}];
oka[n_] := 
  Table[If[Mod[u, 2] != 0 && v == u, 1, 0], {v, 2*n}, {u, 2*n}];
okb[n_] := 
  Table[If[Mod[u, 2] == 0 && v == u, 1, 0], {v, 2*n}, {u, 2*n}];

nvalue = 15;
k = Range[0, 2*Pi, 2*Pi/99];
delta = 0.0;
phi = Pi/2;
t2 = 0.00;
eigvals = 
  Table[N[
    Re[Sort[
      Eigenvalues[
       zigzaghamiltonian[nvalue, k[[i]], t2, phi, delta]]]]], {i, 
    100}] ;

ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[
  Table[{k[[i]], eigvals[[i]][[j]]}, {i, 0, 100}, {j, 0, 2*nvalue}]], 
 PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

Comment: Be careful here: `{i, 0, 100}, {j, 0, 2*nvalue}` Mathematica indexes from 1, not 0. Element 0 is the head e.g `{1, 2, 3}[[0]]` returns `List`. You'll get a Part error when you index `k` or 
 `eigvals` otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

Your code produces a slightly different plot than the one shown in the question. This seems to do what is desired on the graph generated:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[
  Table[{k[[i]], eigvals[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 2*nvalue}]], 
 PlotStyle ->    (* N.B. *)
  ReplacePart[   (* if you know the indices... *)
   ConstantArray[Blue, 2*nvalue],
   {nvalue -> Red, nvalue + 1 -> Red}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't know the indices: `ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[
  Table[{k[[i]], eigvals[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 2*nvalue}]], 
 PlotStyle -> ReplacePart[
   ConstantArray[Blue, 2*nvalue], 
   Position[#, Alternatives @@ MinMax[#]] &[1/eigvals[[1]]] -> Red]]` -- `1/eigvals` works in this case because the eigenvalues are separated by zero.

Answer (score 2):

You may give a separate style to every curve.

Here is a simple example:

```
funs = Table[Sin[x] + i, {i, 4}];
styles = Table[Blue, 4];
styles[[3]] = Red;
Plot[funs, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, PlotStyle -> styles]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
nvalue = 15;

table = Transpose[Table[{k[[i]], eigvals[[i]][[j]]}, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 2 nvalue}]];

ListLinePlot[table, 
 PlotStyle -> ArrayPad[{Red, Red}, nvalue - 1, Blue]]
```

[image]

If the indices of the lines you want to color red is not known, as in

```
shuffledtable = RandomSample[table];
```

and you want to color the two lines closest to the horizontal axis red, you can:

1. Sort `shuffledtable` by the second coordinates of the first points:

```
ListLinePlot[SortBy[#[[1, -1]] &] @ shuffledtable, 
 PlotStyle -> ArrayPad[{Red, Red}, nvalue - 1, Blue]]
```

[image]

2. Alternatively, you can use `Nearest` to identify the two lists nearest the horizontal axis:

```
shuffledtablestyled = MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, shuffledtable, 
   List /@ Nearest[shuffledtable[[All, 1, 2]] -> "Index", 0, 2]];

ListLinePlot[shuffledtablestyled, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is a manual post-processing approach:

During this animation, I use only Simple Click, Double Click and copy-paste.
The double-click is for selecting the Line interactively.

[image]

The two pieces of code that you may not time to read :
`theLine = Cases[, Line[___], Infinity]`

`/. theLine -> {Red, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[3], theLine}`

Answer (score 1):

```
llp =  ListLinePlot[table, PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> Large];
```

Interactively change line colors flipping between `Blue` and `Red` using [`FlipView`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FlipView.html):

```
styles = {Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Blue], Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Red]};

llp /. l_Line :> 
  MouseAppearance[FlipView @ Thread[{styles, l}], "SampleStyle"]
```

[image]